# How do I print these characters in latex?

Tags: latex

I want to print these set of characters (inside double quotes) “`\r\t \n[]<>"?'()!#$%&*+-\/,:;.@`" in LaTeX. How do I do this?

Comment: Did you check any documentation on LaTeX before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the answer by myself

```
$\backslash$r$\backslash$t $\backslash$n[]\textless\textgreater\textquotedblright?\textquoteright()!\#\$\%\&*+-$\backslash$\slash,;:.@
```